# Making two authentication schemes work in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I am developing an ASP.NET 6 Core MVC web application that uses the built-in cookie authentication as its default authentication method.

However, on a few endpoints I also need to authenticate calls that are made without the cookie and instead use a specially formatted header.

Implementing the custom authentication handler was easy (I didn't include it here because I don't think it has anything to do with the issue at hand), however where I am stuck is on how to make a specific endpoint accept both authentication schemes instead of just the default one.

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    //...set cookie options...
});
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddCookie()
    .AddScheme<MyAuthSchemeOptions, MyAuthHandler>("MyCustomAuthScheme", options => { });
services.AddAuthorization(op =>
{
    //Default policy (cookie only)
    var defaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    op.DefaultPolicy = defaultPolicy;

    //Special policy that allows both cookie and my custom authentication scheme
    var allowDesignerAgentPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "MyCustomAuthScheme")
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    op.AddPolicy("MyCustomAuthPolicy", allowDesignerAgentPolicy);
});
```

That code does the following:

- Setup the Cookie authentication
- Register my custom authentication scheme
- Register two policies: the default policy only allows authentication with the default method (cookie), the `MyCustomAuthPolicy` allows both cookie and my custom handler.

Then, in my controller I might have something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult CanOnlyBeCalledWithCookie(){
  //implementation
}

[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Policy = "MyCustomAuthPolicy")]
public IActionResult CanBeCalledWithBothSchemes(){
  //implementation
}
```

This configuration however doesn't work correctly. In particular:

- Calls to endpoints that use the standard default policy work ok
- However, calls to endpoints that use `MyCustomAuthPolicy` only work with my custom authentication method. If they're made with the cookie, the app just returns a `401` error

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**:
did some further testing and I noticed that if I change the registration of the defaul policy and do it like this:

```
//Default policy (cookie only)
        var defaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        op.DefaultPolicy = defaultPolicy;
```

(i.e: if I explicitly set the authentication scheme to `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`) even the calls to the standard endpoints that are only marked with `[Authorize]` stop working. So does this mean that `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` is NOT the correct scheme that the cookie-based authentication is using? Is this why my other policy fails? I'm a bit confused here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after further testing and quite a bit of stepping into the native .NET Core methods with the debugger, it seems that the correct scheme scheme to use for this is `"Identity.Application"`.

If I change the code above to this:

```
//Special policy that allows both cookie and my custom authentication scheme
var allowDesignerAgentPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder("Identity.Application", "MyCustomAuthScheme")
    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
    .Build();
op.AddPolicy("MyCustomAuthPolicy", allowDesignerAgentPolicy);
```

everything now works correctly.

I'm happy this works, but it would be nice to understand why, if anyone has any clarifications feel free to comment.

EDIT: I figured it out. It is because I am using `ASP.NET Core Identity` to manage user identities in the database and apparently when you do that the correct scheme is `IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme`, which maps to the string `"Identity.Application"`